# SQL : Getting cross matching columns with value of both the fields

Tags: sql

Below is the scenario,

Table A

```
---------------------
ID    | Col 1     | Col 2  
---------------------
1     | 1         | 2      
---------------------
2     | 3         | 4           
---------------------
3     | 2         | 1             
---------------------
4     | 4         | 3           
---------------------
```

Here in col 1 there is some data '1' and in col 2 there is some data '2'. In the same table there is another row where these values are interchanged. How can i get the output as below using SQL query

```
ID_1 | Col 1     | Col 2     |ID_2
-----------------------------------
1    | 1         | 2         |3
-----------------------------------
2    | 3         | 4         |4
-----------------------------------
```

I know this option

```
SELECT a.ID, a.col1, a.col2
  FROM tableA a
 WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1
                     FROM tableA b
                    WHERE a.col1 = b.col2
                      AND a.col2 = b.col1
                      AND a.col1 > b.col1 );
```

but i don't know, how to get the second ID

Answer (score 1):

Is this this what you want?

```
select a.*, b.id
from tableA a join
     tableB b
     on a.col1 = b.col2 and a.col2 = b.col1 and a.id < b.id;
```

This will return one row per additional `id` greater than the given id where the values in `col1` and `col2` are reversed.

Here is code that demonstrates that this works:

```
with tablea(id, col1, col2) as (
      values(1, 1, 2), (2, 3, 4), (3, 2, 1), (4, 4, 3)
     )
select a.*, b.id
from tableA a join
     tableA b
     on a.col1 = b.col2 and a.col2 = b.col1 and a.id < b.id;
```

It returns exactly what you specify.  [Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/11893) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: No Sir , I don't want to return one row per additional `id` greater than the given id where the values in `col1` and `col2` are reversed. It will give the below mentioned result  ID|COL_1|COL_2|ID_1
1|1|2|2
3|3|4|4

Comment: @ShubhajitChanda . . . The code works.  It produces the output you specify.